# CSV file being returned as a single string

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs

Here's the relevant code:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult APIDownloadCSV()
{
    var filename = Server.MapPath("~/xxx/test.csv");
    byte[] content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
    return File(content, "text/csv", "test.csv");
}
```

Javascript:

```
var fetchCSV = function () {
    return postDownloadCsv().then(function (data) {
        var hiddenElement = document.createElement("a");
        hiddenElement.href = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + data;
        hiddenElement.target = "_blank";
        hiddenElement.download = "test.csv";
        hiddenElement.click();
        hiddenElement.remove();
    });
}
```

`postDownloadCSV` is just a simple one-line `$http.post` function to the correct URL.

**Problem:**

When I use the above code, the file downloads as a CSV but returns only as a single continuous string. However, when I directly post the URL to the browser's location bar, the file being downloaded is correctly parsed. I've tried manipulating headers so that I'm requesting `text/csv` but it's not working. For reasons, I must not employ a parser on the client-side to fix this (Not that I'd want to, anyway. The file is perfectly alright on the server. Just need to download it.)

I suppose the problem to be in the side of the client as I can download the file through the URL, but where? Am I doing something wrong with my `$http.post`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to encode the href of the link before you set it.

```
hiddenElement.href = encodeURI("data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + data);
```

working js-fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f6enw0L6/

Comment: What do you know, such a simple solution to a problem that has hounded me for hours! Thank you. A much deserved accept.